# Issue with error: Warning: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 508 rowsWarning: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement

Tags: r

my code here is the first iteration of a for loop

```
l <- 255-4-200
u <- 255-4
reg_trailing = lm(cmort_vec ~ design_matrix, subset = design_matrix[l:u,])
new_data <- data.frame(design_matrixx = design_matrix[t, "x"], 
                       design_matrixz = design_matrix[t, "z"], 
                       design_matrixx.1 = design_matrix[t, "x.1"], 
                       design_matrixz.1 = design_matrix[t, "z.1"], 
                       design_matrixx.2 = design_matrix[t, "x.2"], 
                       design_matrixz.2 = design_matrix[t, "z.2"],
                       row.names = NULL)
yhat_trailing_sixf[1] = predict(reg_trailing, newdata = new_data)
```

yhat_trailing_sixf[1] is part of a vector of NAs
design_matrix is a 508 x 6 matrix. I have seen other posts with the same error and the solution was the names don.t match for new data. but mine do.

```
coef(reg_trailing)
new_data
```

[image]

[image]

I want to make a prediction but I cant

Comment: You have not provided enough information for a workable solution. What happens if you just run `predict(reg_trailing, newdata = new_data)`? What is "yhat_trailing_sixf" is it a vector, matrix, data frame? Is it even defined?